# python deleting element from a list of strings

Tags: python

I am trying to remove elements from a list of strings (read from a file). The elements are themselves a list (in the form of a string, separated by commas).

I want to remove those strings from the list that have the same elements. 
For eg:

1: GGSIPU,RANK,BTECH,9

2: GGSIPU,BTECH,RANK,9

3: GGSIPU,BTECH,RANK,9

hence lines 2 and 3 should be removed.

here is my code:

```
# to remove duplicates

with open('itemset3.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    f.close()

i = 0

while (i<len(lines)):
    j = i + 1
    temp = []
    temp1 = lines[i].split(',')
    print 'outer %d %s' % (i,temp1)
    temp.append(temp1[0])
    temp.append(temp1[1])
    temp.append(temp1[2])
    while (j<len(lines)):
        if all(t in lines[j] for t in temp):
            print temp, ' found at ',j,': ',lines[j]
            # lines.remove(lines[j])
            del lines[j] 
        j = j + 1
    i = i + 1

f = open('itemset3.txt', 'w')
i = 0
while (i<len(lines)):
    f.write(lines[i])
    i = i + 1
f.close()
```

and here is the text file

```
GGSIPU,RANK,BTECH,9
GGSIPU,BTECH,RANK,9
GGSIPU,BTECH,RANK,9
GGSIPU,SEMESTER,RANK,9
GGSIPU,CALCULATOR,RANK,9
GGSIPU,CHECK,RANK,7
GGSIPU,Certified,RANK,7
GGSIPU,Winner,RANK,7
GGSIPU,Application,RANK,7
GGSIPU,Techexpo2015,RANK,7
GGSIPU,Students,RANK,6
RANK,BTECH,GGSIPU,9
RANK,BTECH,GGSIPU,9
RANK,BTECH,GGSIPU,9
RANK,SEMESTER,GGSIPU,9
RANK,SEMESTER,GGSIPU,9
RANK,CALCULATOR,GGSIPU,9
RANK,CALCULATOR,GGSIPU,9
RANK,CHECK,GGSIPU,7
RANK,CHECK,GGSIPU,7
RANK,Certified,GGSIPU,7
RANK,Certified,GGSIPU,7
RANK,Winner,GGSIPU,7
RANK,Winner,GGSIPU,7
RANK,Application,GGSIPU,7
RANK,Application,GGSIPU,7
RANK,Techexpo2015,GGSIPU,7
RANK,Techexpo2015,GGSIPU,7
RANK,Students,GGSIPU,6
RANK,Students,GGSIPU,6
BTECH,SEMESTER,GGSIPU,9
BTECH,CALCULATOR,GGSIPU,9
SEMESTER,CALCULATOR,GGSIPU,9
CHECK,Certified,GGSIPU,7
CHECK,Winner,GGSIPU,7
CHECK,Application,GGSIPU,7
CHECK,Techexpo2015,GGSIPU,7
CHECK,Students,GGSIPU,6
Certified,Winner,GGSIPU,7
Certified,Application,GGSIPU,7
Certified,Techexpo2015,GGSIPU,7
Certified,Students,GGSIPU,6
Winner,Application,GGSIPU,7
Winner,Techexpo2015,GGSIPU,7
Winner,Students,GGSIPU,6
Application,Techexpo2015,GGSIPU,7
Application,Students,GGSIPU,6
Techexpo2015,Students,GGSIPU,6
```

The question is that after running the code, there are still some redundant (duplicate) lines in the output. How should I rectify it?

here's the ouput upon making tuples:

```
('Certified', 'Winner', 'GGSIPU', '7')
('RANK', 'Application', 'GGSIPU', '7')
('Techexpo2015', 'Students', 'GGSIPU', '6')
('CHECK', 'Certified', 'GGSIPU', '7')
('RANK', 'SEMESTER', 'GGSIPU', '9')
('Application', 'Techexpo2015', 'GGSIPU', '7')
('GGSIPU', 'SEMESTER', 'RANK', '9')
('CHECK', 'Techexpo2015', 'GGSIPU', '7')
('RANK', 'Winner', 'GGSIPU', '7')
('CHECK', 'Winner', 'GGSIPU', '7')
('Winner', 'Students', 'GGSIPU', '6')
('GGSIPU', 'Winner', 'RANK', '7')
('GGSIPU', 'BTECH', 'RANK', '9')
('RANK', 'Techexpo2015', 'GGSIPU', '7')
('Certified', 'Students', 'GGSIPU', '6')
('GGSIPU', 'CHECK', 'RANK', '7')
('RANK', 'BTECH', 'GGSIPU', '9')
('GGSIPU', 'Students', 'RANK', '6')
('RANK', 'CALCULATOR', 'GGSIPU', '9')
('Winner', 'Techexpo2015', 'GGSIPU', '7')
('GGSIPU', 'Certified', 'RANK', '7')
('RANK', 'CHECK', 'GGSIPU', '7')
('CHECK', 'Application', 'GGSIPU', '7')
('RANK', 'Certified', 'GGSIPU', '7')
('GGSIPU', 'RANK', 'BTECH', '9')
('GGSIPU', 'CALCULATOR', 'RANK', '9')
('CHECK', 'Students', 'GGSIPU', '6')
('GGSIPU', 'Application', 'RANK', '7')
('GGSIPU', 'Techexpo2015', 'RANK', '7')
('Winner', 'Application', 'GGSIPU', '7')
('BTECH', 'SEMESTER', 'GGSIPU', '9')
('Certified', 'Techexpo2015', 'GGSIPU', '7')
('RANK', 'Students', 'GGSIPU', '6')
('SEMESTER', 'CALCULATOR', 'GGSIPU', '9')
('Certified', 'Application', 'GGSIPU', '7')
('Application', 'Students', 'GGSIPU', '6')
('BTECH', 'CALCULATOR', 'GGSIPU', '9')
```

the lines such as the following are still present

1: ('GGSIPU', 'Application', 'RANK', '7')

2: ('RANK', 'Application', 'GGSIPU', '7')

Comment: I see a problem statement, a code sample, and an input sample, but no question.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist `I want to remove those strings from the list that have the same elements`

Comment: The entire point of using `with` when opening a file is that the context manager closes the file for you.

Comment: @Borja Still not a question.

Comment: `I want to remove those strings from the list that have the same elements` aka `how can i remove those strings from the list that have the same elements?`

Comment: "NameOfList".remove("string")

Comment: or just google it. Here's the [document](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) on lists in python .

Comment: @Borja I speak English fine and can rearrange statements into questions ably. I was wondering what question you had that pertained to your code. Either you have a question about all this code you posted, or you are generally asking how to do `X` in which case everything you posted is irrelevant. Tie them together and drill down to your actual problem, please.

Comment: I didn't post anything @Two-BitAlchemist . Again, you can be as tough as you want, but I can see a clear question on this problem.

Comment: @Borja Whoops! Sorry, bouncing between questions and thought you were OP.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist I added the question. Please help me out!

Comment: @Borja But "How do I do [relatively simple task] in [common programming language]?" is too broad. You see **a** question, but is it one that is fit for here?

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('C:\Users\DELL\Documents\itemset3.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    f.close()

linesUp = []
for line in lines:
    linesUp.append(tuple(line.replace("\n","").split(',')))

setOfLines = set(linesUp)
```

I have constructed tuple from the string split at `,` and put them into a list. towards then end created a set which just eliminates duplicates.

> used replace on string `line` because few  string did not have new lines surprisingly in you data.

I have worked with a small set of data. Hope it will work for you

Comment: You have to look at the data file look for any more non printable characters . or try with a test data and look at the result

Comment: i have added the output after creating the tuples

Comment: Please run the above script with your data and see if still duplicated exists if exists, Skip this solution

Answer (score -1):

```
coverting lines into tuples a making sets.

allLines = set()

with open('data') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        line = tuple(line.split(','))
        allLines.add(line)

pp(allLines)



{('Application', 'Students', 'GGSIPU', '6'),
 ('Application', 'Techexpo2015', 'GGSIPU', '7'),
 ('BTECH', 'CALCULATOR', 'GGSIPU', '9'),
 ('BTECH', 'SEMESTER', 'GGSIPU', '9'),
 ('CHECK', 'Application', 'GGSIPU', '7'),
 ('CHECK', 'Certified', 'GGSIPU', '7'),
 ('CHECK', 'Students', 'GGSIPU', '6'),
 ('CHECK', 'Techexpo2015', 'GGSIPU', '7'),
 ('CHECK', 'Winner', 'GGSIPU', '7'),
 ('Certified', 'Application', 'GGSIPU', '7'),
 ('Certified', 'Students', 'GGSIPU', '6'),
 ('Certified', 'Techexpo2015', 'GGSIPU', '7'),
 ('Certified', 'Winner', 'GGSIPU', '7'),
 ('GGSIPU', 'Application', 'RANK', '7'),
 ('GGSIPU', 'BTECH', 'RANK', '9'),
 ('GGSIPU', 'CALCULATOR', 'RANK', '9'),
 ('GGSIPU', 'CHECK', 'RANK', '7'),
 ('GGSIPU', 'Certified', 'RANK', '7'),
 ('GGSIPU', 'RANK', 'BTECH', '9'),
 ('GGSIPU', 'SEMESTER', 'RANK', '9'),
 ('GGSIPU', 'Students', 'RANK', '6'),
 ('GGSIPU', 'Techexpo2015', 'RANK', '7'),
 ('GGSIPU', 'Winner', 'RANK', '7'),
 ('RANK', 'Application', 'GGSIPU', '7'),
 ('RANK', 'BTECH', 'GGSIPU', '9'),
 ('RANK', 'CALCULATOR', 'GGSIPU', '9'),
 ('RANK', 'CHECK', 'GGSIPU', '7'),
 ('RANK', 'Certified', 'GGSIPU', '7'),
 ('RANK', 'SEMESTER', 'GGSIPU', '9'),
 ('RANK', 'Students', 'GGSIPU', '6'),
 ('RANK', 'Techexpo2015', 'GGSIPU', '7'),
 ('RANK', 'Winner', 'GGSIPU', '7'),
 ('SEMESTER', 'CALCULATOR', 'GGSIPU', '9'),
 ('Techexpo2015', 'Students', 'GGSIPU', '6'),
 ('Winner', 'Application', 'GGSIPU', '7'),
 ('Winner', 'Students', 'GGSIPU', '6'),
 ('Winner', 'Techexpo2015', 'GGSIPU', '7')}
```